# failing to iterate over list for querying DynamoDB

Tags: python, list, for-loop, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to query a DynamoDB iterating over a list and it is failing. I mean returning empty JSON. If I run query with single id, I am able to get data.
I am getting data from a file to a list.
Below is my code in loop:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    resid = f.read().splitlines()
for id in resid:
    result = table.query(
        IndexName="partner_resid-index",
        KeyConditionExpression=Key("id").eq(partner_resid[0]),
        FilterExpression=Key("event").eq("active"),
    )
print(result)
```

Even I tried to call using a function, but no luck.
Any suggestions what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The boto3 `query` function returns only a single page of query results. You must check whether this result has a `LastEvaluatedKey` and if it does, send another query, with `ExclusiveStartKey` set to the last `LastEvaluatedKey`, and continue to do that until you get the last page, without `LastEvaluatedKey` set.

The thing is, if your `FilterExpression` filters out a lot of results, you may even get an empty page - and it is possible this is the empty result you're seeing. Note that DynamoDB first reads a page full of data (by default, 1MB of data), and only then applies to it the `FilterExpression`. It is possible to get back an empty page if all those results did not match the filter, and you still need to continue the loop to the next page.

Alternatively, you can use boto3's `paginator` mechanism. It is used like:

```py
got_items = []
paginator = dynamodb.meta.client.get_paginator('query')
for page in paginator.paginate(TableName='name', KeyConditionExpression=...):
    got_items += page['Items']
```

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I am actually pulling all the events matching a GSI and further an event. So one match has multiple events for a case. Such, I have multiple cases.

Comment: It means that I cannot take all events to a single list. I am trying hard to pass a variable to the `KeyConditionExpression=Key(<variable>)`. If this works, I can succeed.

Comment: Also note your example has print(result) with wrong indentation. I don't know if it's a bug in your real code or just a typo in the example.

Comment: I agree, that just a snippet from my code that I have pasted here. Yes, it should be in side  `for` loop

Comment: I figured out what's wrong in my code. If you look at my code snippet above, I gave `partner_resid[0]` which is wrong. I need to mention it as `partner_resid`